# How to use the default colors when specifying patterns in a zone in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have a column chart with multiple series created with [Highcharts.js](https://www.highcharts.com/), in the graph, I have zones for projected values based on trends. I want to visually differentiate these from actual live data.

I want the column chart to show actual data in solid colors (using the default colors of the theme - no color options are being supplied) and diagonal patterns for the projected values using the same colors.

I am passing the options from PHP as a JSON like so:

```php
$h_series['zoneAxis'] = 'x';
$h_series['zones'] = array(
  array('value' => $zone_start),
  array(
    'color' => array(
      'pattern' => array(
        'path' => array(
          'd' => 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
          'strokeWidth' => 2
        ),
        'width' => 10,
        'height' => 10,
        //'color' => '#feafea'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

As you can see I'd like to not specify the `color` option for the zones because I'd like for the series to maintain the color it has originally. But when I remove the `color` option, I get a black pattern.

I saw [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0etopfLs/) which is somewhat what I want to achieve but the color is being manually specified. I don't want to specify colors at all so that everything just uses the default colors.

---

#### Additional Info

I'm doing something similar to a spline graph:

```php
$total_series['zoneAxis'] = 'x';
$total_series['zones'] = array(
  array('value' => $zone_start),
  array('dashStyle' => 'dot')
);
```

Somehow this one works perfectly, it retained the color of the spline, it simply changed from a solid line to a dotted line when the points are within the specified zone. This is what I want to achieve, simply change the solid columns to striped columns if they are within the zone.

---

#### Example

I created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvaux6d7/) for those wanting an example.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
      color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
      from: 2.5,
      to: 4.5
    }]
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
      value: 3
    }, {
      color: {
        pattern: {
          path: {
            d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
            strokeWidth: 3
          },
          width: 10,
          height: 10
        }
      }
    }]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [41.2, 25.6, 30.0, 101.6, 175.2],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
      value: 3
    }, {
      color: {
        pattern: {
          path: {
            d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
            strokeWidth: 3
          },
          width: 10,
          height: 10
        }
      }
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle (only a chart with sample data)? It seems that patterns don't change default colors, compare those demos: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m6kex2wf/1/, https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3z90dp2v/1/.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I edited the question with an example. Please take a look again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is not working with zones.

You can achieve it only by setting pattern colors as default series colors:

```
zones: [{
    value: 3
}, {
    color: {
    pattern: {
        path: {
        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
        strokeWidth: 3
      },
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      color: Highcharts.defaultOptions.colors[0]
    }
  }
}]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u71dk3pa/1/

Or setting them automatically using `chart.events.load` callback:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.series.forEach(function(series) {
          series.points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (typeof point.color !== 'string') {
              point.update({
                color: {
                  pattern: {
                    path: {
                      d: 'M 0 0 L 10 10 M 9 -1 L 11 1 M -1 9 L 1 11',
                      strokeWidth: 3
                    },
                    width: 10,
                    height: 10,
                    color: series.color
                  }
                }
              }, false)
            }
          });
        });

        chart.redraw();
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7vmdnfz5/1/

Comment: I couldn't use your first solution because I'm building the series on the server side using PHP so I can't access `Highcharts.defaultOptions.colors`. However I could do your second solution using the `chart.events.load` callback. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question though since I see you are a Highcharts Developer, do you consider this a bug? Should it not take a series color by default?

Comment: It is not a bug. You're setting zones so the column within a particular zone takes its color and when there is no color set it takes a default zone color (black).